# Perl split string based on forward slash

Tags: regex, perl

I am new to Perl, so this is basic question. I have a string as shown below. I am interested in taking date out of it, so thinking of splitting it using slash

```
my $path = "/bla/bla/bla/20160306";
my $date = (split(/\//,$path))[3];#ideally 3 is date position in array after split
print $date;
```

However, I don't see the expected output, but instead I see 5 getting printed.

Comment: When in doubt to what your variables contain: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \@split;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the path starts with the pattern `/` itself, [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split) returns a list with an empty string first (to the left of the first `/`); one element more. Thus the posted code miscounts by one and returns the one before last element (subdirectory) in the path, not the date.

If date is always the last thing in the string you can pick the last element

```
my $date = (split '/', $path)[-1];
```

where i've used `''` for delimiters so to not have to escape `/`.  (This, however, may confuse since the separator pattern *is a [regex](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut)* and `//` convey that, while `''` may appear to merely quote a string.)

---

This can also be done with regex

```
my @parts = $path =~ m{([^/]+)}g;
```

With this there can be no inital empty string.  Or, the last part can be picked out of the full list as above, with `($path =~ m{...}g)[-1]`, but if you indeed only need the last bit then extract it directly

```
my ($last_part) = $path =~ m{.*/(.*)};
```

Here the "greedy" `.*` matches everything in the string up to the last instance of the next subpattern (`/` here), thus getting us to the last part of the path, which is then captured.  The regex match operator returns its matches only when it is in the *list context* so parens on the left are needed.

---

What brings us to the fact that you are parsing a path, and there are libraries dedicated to that.

For splitting a path into its components one tool is `splitdir` from [File::Spec](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Spec.html)

```
use File::Spec;

my @parts = File::Spec->splitdir($path);
```

If the path starts with a `/` we'll again get an empty string for the first element (by design, see docs).  That can then be removed, if there

```
shift @parts if $parts[0] eq '';
```

Again, the last element alone can be had like in the other examples.

Comment: Can't use '/' as '/' needs to be parsed into the function as a string.

Comment: @Owl "_Can't use '/' as '/' needs to be parsed into the function as a string_" -- I don't understand that? In the first example the `/` is the pattern to split the string by. What "_function_" does it need to be "_parsed into_"?  It's a part of the string to process and `split` breaks the string up into parts around all `/` that it finds.  (All examples here have been tested and work, try them out.)

Comment: I solved it it needed to be delimited by a \ first before / if it's in a string. Basically there was a variable containing "/" and it needed to be "\/" for it to work. i've no doubt that '/' would work, but apparently not when the split splits on a variable.

Comment: @Owl I still don't get it -- if the pattern in `split` is delimited by a other character than the `/` itself then we don't need to escape the `/` in the pattern (as I tried to explain in the answer?).  So `split m{/}` is fine, and so is `split m|/|` and `split m#/#` ... etc.  Using quotes is specially allowed (so there is no need for `m`), so `split '/'` or `split "/"` is OK as well. Now, if one wants the usual `/.../` for delimiters _then_ indeed we need to escape it, `split /\//`.  Is this what you are saying?

Comment: @Owl The argument of `split` for a separator  is a [regular expression](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut), and so it need be treated by those syntax rules.   I added links to the answer. Except that the quotes are specially allowed  (in a normal regex one would have to put `m` in front, `$v =~ m"pattern"`)

Answer (score 1):

Simply bind it to the end:

```
(\d+)$
# look for digits at the end of the string
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pR0cC8/1). The capturing group is only for clarification though not really needed in this case.

In `Perl` this would be (I am a PHP/Python guy, so bear with me when it is ugly)

```
my $path = "/bla/bla/bla/20160306";
$path =~ /(\d+)$/;
print $1;
```

See [a demo on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/tEVIOZ).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Use look ahead for to do it. It capture the `/` by splitting. Then substitute the data using `/` for remove the slash.

```
my $path = "/a/b/c/20160306";
my $date = (split(/(?=\/)/,$path))[3];
$date=~s/^\///;
print $date;
```

Or else use pattern matching with grouping for to do it.

```
my $path = "/a/b/c/20160306";
my @data = $path =~m/\/(\w+)/g;
print $data[3];
```